# Wrong email body in transactional email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, transactional

I'm using the contacts module to output different contactforms in different stores in a multishop environment.

I insert my contact form like this:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml" form_action="/mycontacts/index/post"}}
```

I created some transactional email templates, one per store.

In backend I choose different email-templates, one per store.

This all works. And I receive E-Mails.

**But here is my problem**:

The email I receive **has proper subject**: the subject I entered in System->transactional emails-> template XY

But the **mail body seems to be some other**

This is my system email template:

```
Name:       {{var data.vorname}} {{var data.name}}
Firma:      {{var data.company}

Straße:     {{var data.street}}
Ort:       {{var data.city}}
Land:     {{var data.land}}

E-Mail:     {{var data.email}}
Telefon:    {{var data.telephone}}
Kommentar:  {{var data.comment}}
```

This is what I receive:

```
Name:        MyName
Firma:      
Ort:       MyCity
Land:     

E-Mail:     MyEmail 
Telefon:    MyTelephone
Kommentar:  MyComment
```

How can this be?

Comment: visit link give solustion:-http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/25/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates/\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging I found my mistake:

There was an erroneous data-Tag:

```
Firma:      {{var data.company}
```

But it has to be:

```
Firma:      {{var data.company}}
```